# Does parent object know its children in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Let’s say we have:

```
var parent = {};
var child = Object.create(parent);
```

Can parent enumerate children and use their properties and methods somehow?
Yes, I can create an array of children. However, there’s a possibility to forget to do it with another new child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregarding the unorthodox terminology, you can't enforce **inheriting instances** from adhering to anything and as a result there is no reliable way to do what you seek to do.

Try a Post-It ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You will need some reference. An object does not know its parent automatically. But instead of saving an index, I think you can save the parent object itself. The parent is stored by reference, so if the parent is modified, the parent reference of the child reflects those changes. This is shown below in a slightly altered version of your code:

```
function parent() {
    this.index = 0;
    // Make children a property (for this test case) and 
    // pass 'this' (the parent itself) to a child's constructor.
    this.children = [new child(this)];
}

function child(parent) {
    // Store the parent reference.
    this.parent = parent;
}

// Do this after the functions are declared. ;)
var parents = [new parent()];

// Set a property of the parent.
parents[0].test = "Hello";

// Read back the property through the parent property of a child.
alert(parents[0].children[0].parent.test); // Shows "Hello"
```

Comment: As I said, there’s no problem to solve it with a manual array of children.
My question lays in the built-in inheritance features in the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a parent/child relationship.
That's a prototypal-inheritance link.

Prototypal inheritance is not the same.

```
const a = { x: 1, y: 2, doZ () { } };
const b = Object.create(a);
b.__proto__ === a; // true
```

The old-fashioned version of this was to do something like:

```
function A (x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

A.prototype.doZ = function () { };

var a = new A(1, 2);

function B () { }
B.prototype = a;


var b = new B();
var c = new B();
var d = new B();
```

Should `a` be allowed to iterate over all instances of `B`?
Not really, no.

Comment: Thanks a lot.

I’ve seen lots of weird things in JavaScript. So, I presumed that parent could know something about its children ;)

And what do you mean by ‘old fashioned way’? As I know, using __proto__ is a bad practice. Jshint, as I see, prohibits this way.

Comment: @zhekaus using `__proto__` directly is a practice that will cause crashes on older browsers (as `__proto__` existed under the covers, but was not directly accessible).  Using function constructor inheritance in the exact way I demonstrated as the "old-fashioned" way is very 2005.  Except that `Object.create` does the same thing, under the covers, without you having to write constructors, and instantiate them.  In both cases `b.__proto__ === a`. A is B’s prototype. A prototype is not a parent/child relationship. It’s a base-idea/clone relationship. The clone then adds improvements over top.

Comment: @zhekaus Also, in the future, as you move toward the new version of the language, in projects, you might consider moving to ESLint, unless JSHint has finished its internal overhauls to its static analysis system. And `Object.assign` is brand new (but standard spec), and will crash in old browsers. But it can be found in most libraries, as `extends`. Underscore/Lodash, jQuery, Angular < 2, et cetera, all have this behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, that last bit (`Object.assign`) was good information, but about the wrong SO question, also to do with inheritance (solving multiple-inheritance, using Traits, instead).